# Example CrossEntropyLoss for 3D semantic segmentation in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have a network performing 3D convolutions on a 5D input tensor. The output of my network if of size (1, 12, 60, 36, 60) corresponding to ( BatchSize, NumClasses, x-dim, y-dim, z-dim). I need to compute a voxel-wise cross entropy loss. However I keep on getting errors.

When trying to compute cross entropy loss using `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`, I keep on getting the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at .../src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:16
```

here is the extract of my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
images = Variable(torch.randn(1, 12, 60, 36, 60)).cuda()
labels = Variable(torch.zeros(1, 12, 60, 36, 60).random_(2)).long().cuda()
loss = criterion(images.view(1,-1), labels.view(1,-1))
```

Same happens when I create a one-hot tensor for the labels:

```
nclasses = 12
labels = (np.random.randint(0,12,(1,60,36,60))) # Random labels with values between [0..11]
labels = (np.arange(nclasses) == labels[..., None] - 1).astype(int) # Converts labels to one_hot_tensor
a = np.transpose(labels,(0,4,3,2,1)) #  Reorder dimensions to match shape of "images" ([1, 12, 60, 36, 60])
b = Variable(torch.from_numpy(a)).cuda()
loss = criterion(images.view(1,-1), b.view(1,-1))
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Can someone provide an example of computing cross entropy on a 5D output tensor?

Answer (score 1):

Just checked some implementation ([fcn](https://github.com/wkentaro/pytorch-fcn/blob/master/torchfcn/trainer.py)) for 2D semantic segmentation, and tried to adapt it to 3D semantic segmentation. No guarantee that this is correct, I'll have to double check...

```
 import torch
 import torch.nn.functional as F
 def cross_entropy3d(input, target, weight=None, size_average=True):
    # input: (n, c, h, w, z), target: (n, h, w, z)
    n, c, h, w , z = input.size()
    # log_p: (n, c, h, w, z)
    log_p = F.log_softmax(input, dim=1)
    # log_p: (n*h*w*z, c)
    log_p = log_p.permute(0, 4, 3, 2, 1).contiguous().view(-1, c) # make class dimension last dimension
    log_p = log_p[target.view(n, h, w, z, 1).repeat(1, 1, 1, 1, c) >= 0] # this looks wrong -> Should rather be a one-hot vector
    log_p = log_p.view(-1, c)
    # target: (n*h*w*z,)
    mask = target >= 0
    target = target[mask]
    loss = F.nll_loss(log_p, target.view(-1), weight=weight, size_average=False)
    if size_average:
        loss /= mask.data.sum()
    return loss
images = Variable(torch.randn(5, 3, 16, 16, 16))
labels = Variable(torch.LongTensor(5, 16, 16, 16).random_(3))
cross_entropy3d(images, labels, weight=None, size_average=True)
```

Comment: Have you solve it? I am finding the way to do it, because I am using 3D Unet

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) explain this behavior (bottom line, it looks like it's actually computing the *sparse* Cross Entropy Loss, thereby not requiring targets for all dimensions of the output, but only the index of the required one) ... they specifically state:

```
Input: (N,C), where C = number of classes
Target: (N), where each value is 0 <= targets[i] <= C-1
Output: scalar. If reduce is False, then (N) instead.
```

I'm not sure about your use-case, but you might want to use the [KL Divergence](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.KLDivLoss) or the [Binary Cross Entropy Loss](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) instead. Both are defined over inputs and targets of equal size.